# Setting variable to result of Google Visualization Data Aggregation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, charts, google-visualization

Below is my function which draws a gauge chart using `google.visualization.data.group()` and `google.visualization.data.sum` .

See fiddle for working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/xmcqyuqc/7/

```
    function drawChart() {

    var urlString = '../Logs/clnLogsSelectingEvents?grade=All&SC=1&CauseSC=3&CutOffDate=01/01/2017';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        //url: urlString,       //I have commented out but this is my original source.
        success: function (result) {

            //Create DataTable
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            //Add Columns
            data.addColumn('string', 'CW');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Business Division');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Product');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Cost');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Age (d)');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Actual State');

            //Add Rows
            var dataArray = [];
            //replaced with manual sample data     
            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
              dataArray.push([      
                'CW' + i,
                'GS',
                'line' + i,
                10,
                99,
                99,
                'state' + i
              ]);        
            }
            data.addRows(dataArray);

            //Create Data View
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([1, 3]);

            //Create Data Aggregation
            var groupView = google.visualization.data.group(view, [{
                column: 0,
                type: 'string'
            }], [{
                column: 1,
                aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
                type: 'number'
            }]);

            //Options
            var options = {   
                max: '150'      ///I want to set this based on the result of the aggregation
            };

            //Instantiate and draw chart, passing in options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(groupView, options);

    }   //END  success: function (result) {
  });     //END  $.ajax({
}           //END  function drawChart()
```

I have set the max hard coded 150.

```
var options = {   
   max: '150' 
};
```

I want to set the max to a calculated value of 3 times the aggregated sum.

Example:  `google.visualization.data.sum` returns 50 * 3 = 150 max value

I don't know the best way to do this and can't get a variable set to the `google.visualization.data.sum` value which the aggregation calculated.

Would appreciate some assistance from the gurus!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.visualization.data.group` returns a regular [`DataTable` class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class)

use [chart method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getValue) `getValue` to get the value in the group table

`getValue(rowIndex, colIndex)`

the group table in the post returns one row,
so use the following to the know the value...

```
groupView.getValue(0, 1)
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['gauge']
});

function drawChart() {
  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  //Add Columns
  data.addColumn('string', 'CW');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Business Division');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Product');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cost');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Age (d)');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Actual State');

  //Add Rows
  var dataArray = [];
  //replaced with manual sample data
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dataArray.push([
      'CW' + i,
      'GS',
      'line' + i,
      10,
      99,
      99,
      'state' + i
    ]);
  }
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  //Create Data View
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([1, 3]);

  //Create Data Aggregation
  var groupView = google.visualization.data.group(view, [{
      column: 0,
      type: 'string'
  }], [{
      column: 1,
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
      type: 'number'
  }]);

  //Options
  var options = {
      max: groupView.getValue(0, 1)
  };

  //Instantiate and draw chart, passing in options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(groupView, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```